# Trying to validate string only has numbers or letters (and can contain spaces)

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a validation on a string but for some reason, special characters keep getting through and I just cannot figure out what I am missing here.

Here is what I currently have in the model

```
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /[a-z0-9A-Z]/ , :message => "is not valid" }
```

I have also tried

```
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-z0-9A-Z]\z/ , :message => "is not valid" }
```

I need to validate that a string only has letters or numbers in it, and can have a space.  So `test 03` would be valid, but `test ***` would not.  For some reason that last one keeps getting through even though when I run the regex here https://rubular.com/ it does not match to those characters, which should cause this validation to fail I would think.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using RUBY, however, try this regex syntax - this would require only a-zA-Z0-9 and at least one character:

```
/\A[a-z0-9A-Z ]+\z/
```

OR this one, if string can be of a length = 0:

```
/\A^[a-z0-9A-Z ]*\z/
```

-- updated to include support for space

Comment: so with this I get a failed validation, I think because of a space, so this fails `test 09`, but should pass

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to edit to make it work specifically in ruby, which complains about the `^` and `$` characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    \A            # match the beginning of the string
    [ \p{Alnum}]  # match a space, digit or Unicode letter in a character class
    +             # repeat one or more times
    \z            # match the end of the string
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

"I am told that 007 prefers zinfandel to rosé".match? r
  #=> true 
"007, I am told, prefers zinfandel to rosé".match? r
  #=> false
```

Note that the use of (the "`\p{} construct`") `\p{Alnum}` (or the comparable POSIX expression `[[:alnum:]]`) is not only useful for non-English text but also for words with diacritical marks that have made their way into the Enlish language, such as "rosé" (which cannot very well be written "rose"). These expressions are documented in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) (search within the file).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21915974)

Comment: @U9-Forward, please explain why this (the regex) does not answer the question.

Comment: @U9-Forward, come on, the explanation is obvious. What do you want me to say, "For any string `str`, the test of whether the string meets the test is `str.match? /\A[\p{Alnum} ]+ ]+/`"? Should I then go on to break down the trivial regex? Tell me if the accepted answer to this question provides any fuller of an explanation. If you look at my other answers you will see that I often provide gory detail. It's just not needed here.